# Bug when testing the setup of Model and Migration connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, yarnpkg, sequelize-cli

I'm currently doing a backend connection with a db, using node, postgresql and sequelize as orm. I've been getting the same error when I try to make a test using the route and creating a static user, since I haven't created the Controller yet, just to get an response.json. The error is:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","name","email","password_hash","admin","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING "id","name","email","password_hash","admin","createdAt","updatedAt";
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error

 name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: relation "Users" does not exist

 original: error: relation "Users" does not exist
```

I've already tried changing the Model name, the name used in the created migration, using freezeTableName and also defining a name for the tableName. I will send all steps i've done, please, I really need some help here, been stuck with this for 2 days already, I will explode my computer for real...

First, i've configured the settings of the sequelize to show the folders paths(.sequelizerc):

```
const { resolve } = require('path')


module.exports = {
    config: resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'config', 'database.js'),
    'models-path': resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'app', 'models' ),
    'migrations-path': resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations')
}
```

and a few configurations on how the sequelize will read the User Model(database.js):

```
module.exports = {
  dialect: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  username: "postgres",
  password: "jhschier",
  database: "jojosburger",
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscore: true,
    underscoreAll: true,
    freezeTimeTable: true,
  },
};
```

Afterwards I created the first migration using

> yarn sequelize migration:create --name=create-users

And configured the UP and DOWN methods(20240109145449-create-users.js):

```
"use strict";

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable("users", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },

      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },

      password_hash: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      admin: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("users");
  },
};
```

Then, migrated using the sequelize-cli, and checked if the migration was done on PostBird. It was.

> yarn sequelize db:migrate

[Postbird check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkyXl.png)

After the migration was done, I went for the first Model, the User (User.js).

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from "sequelize";
import { define } from "../../config/database";

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        password_hash: Sequelize.STRING,
        admin: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      },
      {
        freezeTableName: true,
      }
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

And did its config at the migrations folder(index.js):

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

import User from "../app/models/User.js";
import configDatabase from "../config/database";

const models = [User];

class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.connection = new Sequelize(configDatabase);
    models.map((model) => model.init(this.connection));
  }
}

export default new Database();
```

At the end, I went to the routes.js to make the test:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

import User from "./app/models/User";

const routes = new Router();

routes.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  const users = await User.create({
    id: v4(),
    name: "JoJo",
    email: "jhschier30@hotmail.com",
    password_hash: "123321",
    admin: true,
  });

  return response.json(users);
});

export default routes;
```

And when I try localhost:3000 I always get a connection error and that huge error in my terminal, can't even fetch the .json from it. As I said, tried changing the name from 'users' to 'user', to 'User', to 'Users', and still the same error. Tried defining freezeTimeTable at both I will be eternally thankful for some help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The issue here is defined in the error message which states "relation "Users" does not exist", in most cases this is from a typo in your table name or table was not created. You can start by verifying that the table is created, double check the table name in the database, ensure you can run select statements with the table name. If it all works, specify the correct table name in your insert statement . Hope this helps